# xCode 5.1 Linker Error No such file or directory: 'load'

Tags: ios, xcode

I have recently created an app and when attempting to archive i receive the following error message:

```
Ld /Users/chris/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PulseGuard_HR_Indicator-amlztlldngwhtvdhgshviupwyhbk/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/PulseGuardLite/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/PulseGuard\ HR\ Indicator.build/Release-iphoneos/PulseGuard\ HR\ Indicator.build/Objects-normal/armv7/PulseGuard\ HR\ Indicator normal armv7
    cd "/Users/chris/Desktop/Projects/PulseGuard Heart Rate Evaluation/PulseGuardHeartRateEvaluation"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk -L/Users/chris/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PulseGuard_HR_Indicator-amlztlldngwhtvdhgshviupwyhbk/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/PulseGuardLite/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -L/Users/chris/Desktop/Projects/PulseGuard\ Heart\ Rate\ Evaluation/PulseGuardHeartRateEvaluation/TestFlightSDK1-1 -F/Users/chris/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PulseGuard_HR_Indicator-amlztlldngwhtvdhgshviupwyhbk/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/PulseGuardLite/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/chris/Desktop/Projects/PulseGuard\ Heart\ Rate\ Evaluation/PulseGuardHeartRateEvaluation/WahooFitnessSDK/dependencies -filelist /Users/chris/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PulseGuard_HR_Indicator-amlztlldngwhtvdhgshviupwyhbk/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/PulseGuardLite/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/PulseGuard\ HR\ Indicator.build/Release-iphoneos/PulseGuard\ HR\ Indicator.build/Objects-normal/armv7/PulseGuard\ HR\ Indicator.LinkFileList -dead_strip -lstdc++ -all load -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -lTestFlight -framework WFConnector -lstdc++.6 -lc++ -framework CoreData -framework CoreBluetooth -framework AVFoundation -framework AudioToolbox -framework MediaPlayer -lz -framework ExternalAccessory -framework MessageUI -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/chris/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PulseGuard_HR_Indicator-amlztlldngwhtvdhgshviupwyhbk/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/PulseGuardLite/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/PulseGuard\ HR\ Indicator.build/Release-iphoneos/PulseGuard\ HR\ Indicator.build/Objects-normal/armv7/PulseGuard\ HR\ Indicator_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/chris/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PulseGuard_HR_Indicator-amlztlldngwhtvdhgshviupwyhbk/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/PulseGuardLite/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/PulseGuard\ HR\ Indicator.build/Release-iphoneos/PulseGuard\ HR\ Indicator.build/Objects-normal/armv7/PulseGuard\ HR\ Indicator

clang: error: no such file or directory: 'load'
```

I have searched through the forums and have found related error messages but none which actually match this one.

I have tried removing and linking my frameworks again and have tried removing arm64 as well from the architecture however this has not helped. I am pretty new to this and am struggling to find the answer so if any one can explain to me where i have gone wrong i would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo, presumably in your Xcode *Other Linker Flags*, where:

```
-all load
```

should be:

```
-all_load
```

Comment: Amazing, that fixed it, thank you so much for your help. Can't believe i missed that one.